# Android foreground service notification not showing in status bar

Tags: java, android, service, intentservice

I have tried various solution here on SO and can't seem to get any of them to work. The notification simply will not show. Can anyone point out where possible issues in my code could be?

```
private void startRunningInForeground() {

        setupNotificationChannel();

        Intent showTaskIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        showTaskIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        showTaskIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        showTaskIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                showTaskIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_logo);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.merge_notif_title));
        builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.merge_notif_description));
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setOngoing(true);

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private void setupNotificationChannel() {
        // Only run this on versions of Android that require notification channels.
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return;
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(notificationManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NotificationChannel cachingChannel = new NotificationChannel(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
                getString(R.string.merge_channel), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        cachingChannel.setDescription(getString(R.string.merge_channel_description));
        cachingChannel.enableLights(false);
        cachingChannel.enableVibration(false);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(cachingChannel);
    }
```

Not receiving any any error messages and the notification channel is being created because I see it in the app settings.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @ZhanbolatRaimbekov in my answer below. I extended Service instead of IntentService and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get it to work by extending Service instead of IntentService.  I cannot give an explanation as to why this worked, but everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What does your startForeground do?

try modify this and make sure your os is > Android 8.0

btw the Channel only needs to be created once.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getApplicationContext(),
            NOTIFICATION_ID, <---
            showTaskIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build()); <--
```

Maybe because of Android O bg service restrictions

```
//Start service:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  startForegroundService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
} else {
  startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
}
```

Comment: startForeground is a method from the intentservice class. It's an Android function and I can't be modified.